# How can I send the result of the operation to the same template where the user submited the form using a django FormView?

Tags: python, django

Well I want to display the result of an operation which is computed when the user submits the data. The problem I'm facing is that I want to use the same template and the FormView class displayed below.

This is the tempalte. Notice that there is a result if statement at the end of it, where the result of the operation should be displayed:

```
# template
{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
         <p style="color: red;">
            Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
         </p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="#" method="post">
        <table>{{ form.as_table }}</table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>

    {% if res %}
        <p>Result: {{ res|floatformat:3 }}</p>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{% url logs_page %}">Logs page</a>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the views.py file. Notice that I'm trying to send the variable 'result' to the form

```
# views.py
class OperationView(FormView):
   def form_valid(self, form):
      cd = form.clean()
      logged_user = self.request.user
      result = compute_result(cd)
      return super(OperationView, self).form_valid(form, {'result': result})
```

Comment: That belongs in forms.py because it is a form. As far as your question is concerned, could you please elaborate and be clearer. You can reuse html templates but I am not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: Well I have a template with form, and I want the suer to enter some numbers and operations and then submit it so in my OperationView class I want to display the unbound form if its a GET request and to show the result right under the form if its a valid POST request. 

My problem is that I dont know how to send that variable 'result' to the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to go to a class based view, as such:

```
class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        my_form = Formname()
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'my_form': my_form})

    def post(self, request):
        my_form = Formname(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            result = do_stuff()
            return render(request, 'template.html', {'my_form': my_form, 'result': result})
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'my_form': my_form})
```

Comment: Yeah good approach. I have solved it by returning the same render in form_valid() method. But I still think that both solutions aren't as ellegant as I was expecting from django :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view where the user submits the form from the template and render the same template from that view including the submitted data.